# Loopback OAuth2 Authentification

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I've got an issue when trying to protect my loopback endpoints with the oauth2 component.
I use a custom user model and a custom application model. 
Here's are my oauth2 options

```
var options = {
      dataSource: app.dataSources.db, // Data source for oAuth2 metadata persistence
      userModel: 'LAccount',
      applicationModel: 'LOAuthClientApp',
      resourceServer: true,
      authorizationServer: true,
      //useAccessTokenModel: true,
      authorizePath: '/oauth/authorize',
      tokenPath: '/oauth/token',
      supportedGrantTypes: [
         'clientCredentials',
         'refreshToken',
         'resourceOwnerPasswordCredentials'
      ]
    };

     var oauth2 = require('loopback-component-oauth2').oAuth2Provider(
      app, // The app instance
      options // The options
    );
```

I'm trying to protect some of my api endpoints

```
app.use([ '/api/mymodel/whoami', '/coordinator_noscope'], oauth2.authenticate({session: false}));
  router.get('/coordinator_noscope', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.accessToken);
    res.json({ 'result': 'done' });
  });
```

Here my "MyModel" route

```
  MyModel.remoteMethod('whoami', {
        accepts: {arg: "options", type: "object", http: "optionsFromRequest"},
        returns: { arg: 'object', type: 'object', root: true },
        http: {path: '/whoami', verb: 'get'}
  });
  MyModel.whoami = function(options, callback) {
      console.log(options.accessToken);
      callback(null, new Success('done'));
  };
```

When I'm getting an access token with a client (with the /oauth/authorize), the /coordinator_noscope route works, but the /api/mymodel/whoami get me a 401 (AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED) error ..

I don't have any acls configured on "MyModel" model.
I don't understand what is the auth difference between the router.get route and the loopback api routes